# Can't extract opposite elements

Tags: r

I am trying to extract some elements from the vector all.variables as follow :
Note that vectors has high shape but here i give you an example :

this is the first vector :

```
> new.var<-unique(most.correlated$Var1)
> new.var[1:10]
 [1] "5a648a09d" "86f13324d" "343042ed9" "29eddc376" "7a34c9e13" "ebbd8432c" "4a20b79b4" "f553483a0" "22abeffb6"
[10] "c4de134af"
```

The second one is :

```
> all.variables<-as.vector(most.correlated$Var1)
> all.variables[1:10]
 [1] "5a648a09d" "86f13324d" "343042ed9" "29eddc376" "7a34c9e13" "ebbd8432c" "4a20b79b4" "f553483a0" "22abeffb6"
[10] "c4de134af"
```

Then I need to extract from the vector `all.variables` elements which are **NOT**  included in both of tow vectors `all.variables` and  `new.var`.
So I write this code:

```
delete.variables<-all.variables[which(!all.variables %in% new.var)]
```

the result is :

```
> delete.variables
character(0)
```

this is weird because in the real case, it should give a vector containing many elements! I didn't understand what's the problem here?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: All the elemente in `all.variables` are included in `new.var`. Do you want to extract the duplicates?

Comment: @JuanAntonioRoldánDíaz, no I want to extract not needed variables when I did the correlation matrix. in fact, just keep only one variable from each well correlated pairs

Comment: @JuanAntonioRoldánDíaz, this how i get the `most.correlated` matrix `most.correlated<-subset(as.data.frame(correlated.data),abs(value)>=0.7)
str(most.correlated)`

Comment: But then in `all.variables` you should get the name of the variables from `correlated.data` not `most.correlated`.

Comment: @JuanAntonioRoldánDíaz, no the name of the data frame having all well correlated pairs is named `most.correlated`

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand, the `unique` of a vector always includes all the different elements of the vector, then `all.variables %in% new.var` returns `TRUE` for all the elements.

Comment: _elements which are NOT included in both of tow vectors all.variables and  new.var_, you need just the elements in `all.variables` but not in `new.var`, correct. If so, `all.variables[!all.variables %in% new.var]` can get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work. Remove the exclamation mark and add minus sign

```
delete.variables<-all.variables[-which(all.variables %in% new.var)]
```

Answer (score 0):

there is nice function anti_join in dplyr which can select such elements

```
data.frame(name=allvar)%>% anti_join(data.frame(name=newvar), by="name")
```